# following sites in 2013

Tags: 2013

Quick question

When following a site, will the user be informed if a new document is uploaded into a library that is part of that site?  I cant find any info on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my testing on office 365, it doesn't seem to notify you in anyway. 
But there are other options, as you have always been able to you can setup an alert on the document library that will email/sms you when items are added/edited. Also one of the new features are that you can follow single items, if you do that, then you will get a notification in your newsfeed when the item is modified.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  It seems a real shame that following a site doesnt update the user when documents are added updated.  Following a document is fine but a user clicking to follow hundreds of documents would be a problem.  Setting an alert of the library is a good workaround but it would be so much better if it just updated your news feed.  A little dissaointing really

Comment: I supposed it would spam the newsfeed on very active sharepoint installations, so that is probably why it's not a default feature. But it should be possible to build a custom app/solution that does what you are looking for, but I would never enable if farm wide, but for specific libraries I can see the use for it.